# css rearrange the containers

Tags: html, css

I want to create something similar to this one:

[image: Already Available]

... and have it in flex, so it will rearrange. I don't know why I can't get to rearrange it to the right side (it overlaps on top of the chart). See the below what I have got:

[image: what I have got so far]

I would like it to be at the right side, and occupy the rest of the window. How can I arrange this with CSS?

In simple terms, I would like to have the green container to the right side, and when making smaller the navigator, and the green container to flex and go under the red container. I am trying to do this, but for some reason it’s not happening.

I dont uderstand why the right container goes to right side of the first column.

Here’s my snippet:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.general {
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  margin-top: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #4f6d7a;
}
.enlaces {
  float: center;
  display: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #166088;
}
.tablas_carpetas {
  position:grid;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #DBE9EE;
}
.tablas {
  position:left;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction:column;
  order: 1;
  background-color: #dfc0c0;
  height: 300px;

}
.tablas > div {
  display:right;
  float:right;
  background: #ddd;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}
.tablas_carpetas > .carpetas {
  display:flex;

  position:left;
  order: 2;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
.anuncios{
  float: center;
  display: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
.pie{
  float: center;
  display: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#botones").mouseenter(function () {
      $("#resto").show();
    });
    $("#botones").mouseleave(function () {
      $("#resto").hide();
    });
  });
</script>
<div class="general">
  <div class="enlaces"></div>
  <div class="tablas_carpetas">
    <div class="tablas">
      <div>AA</div>
      <div>AKo</div>
      <div>AQo</div>
      <div>AJo</div>
      <div>ATo</div>
      <div>A9o</div>
      <div>A8o</div>
      <div>A7o</div>
      <div>A6o</div>
      <div>A5o</div>
      <div>A4o</div>
      <div>A3o</div>
      <div>A2o</div>

      <div>AKs</div>
      <div>KK</div>
      <div>KQo</div>
      <div>KJo</div>
      <div>KTo</div>
      <div>K9o</div>
      <div>K8o</div>
      <div>K7o</div>
      <div>K6o</div>
      <div>K5o</div>
      <div>K4o</div>
      <div>K3o</div>
      <div>K2o</div>

      <div>AQs</div>
      <div>KQs</div>
      <div>QQ</div>
      <div>QJo</div>
      <div>QTo</div>
      <div>Q9o</div>
      <div>Q8o</div>
      <div>Q7o</div>
      <div>Q6o</div>
      <div>Q5o</div>
      <div>Q4o</div>
      <div>Q3o</div>
      <div>Q2o</div>

      <div>AJs</div>
      <div>KJs</div>
      <div>QJs</div>
      <div>JJ</div>
      <div>JTo</div>
      <div>J9o</div>
      <div>J8o</div>
      <div>J7o</div>
      <div>J6o</div>
      <div>J5o</div>
      <div>J4o</div>
      <div>J3o</div>
      <div>J2o</div>

      <div>ATs</div>
      <div>KTs</div>
      <div>QTs</div>
      <div>JTs</div>
      <div>TT</div>
      <div>T9o</div>
      <div>T8o</div>
      <div>T7o</div>
      <div>T6o</div>
      <div>T5o</div>
      <div>T4o</div>
      <div>T3o</div>
      <div>T2o</div>

      <div>A9s</div>
      <div>K9s</div>
      <div>Q9s</div>
      <div>J9s</div>
      <div>T9s</div>
      <div>99</div>
      <div>98o</div>
      <div>97o</div>
      <div>96o</div>
      <div>95o</div>
      <div>94o</div>
      <div>93o</div>
      <div>92o</div>

      <div>A8s</div>
      <div>K8s</div>
      <div>Q8s</div>
      <div>J8s</div>
      <div>T8s</div>
      <div>98s</div>
      <div>88</div>
      <div>87o</div>
      <div>86o</div>
      <div>85o</div>
      <div>84o</div>
      <div>83o</div>
      <div>82o</div>

      <div>A7s</div>
      <div>K7s</div>
      <div>Q7s</div>
      <div>J7s</div>
      <div>T7s</div>
      <div>97s</div>
      <div>87s</div>
      <div>77</div>
      <div>76o</div>
      <div>75o</div>
      <div>74o</div>
      <div>73o</div>
      <div>72o</div>

      <div>A6s</div>
      <div>K6s</div>
      <div>Q6s</div>
      <div>J6s</div>
      <div>T6s</div>
      <div>96s</div>
      <div>86s</div>
      <div>76s</div>
      <div>66</div>
      <div>65o</div>
      <div>64o</div>
      <div>63o</div>
      <div>62o</div>

      <div>A5s</div>
      <div>K5s</div>
      <div>Q5s</div>
      <div>J5s</div>
      <div>T5s</div>
      <div>95s</div>
      <div>85s</div>
      <div>75s</div>
      <div>65s</div>
      <div>55</div>
      <div>54o</div>
      <div>53o</div>
      <div>52o</div>

      <div>A4s</div>
      <div>K4s</div>
      <div>Q4s</div>
      <div>J4s</div>
      <div>T4s</div>
      <div>94s</div>
      <div>84s</div>
      <div>74s</div>
      <div>64s</div>
      <div>54s</div>
      <div>44</div>
      <div>43o</div>
      <div>42o</div>

      <div>A3s</div>
      <div>K3s</div>
      <div>Q3s</div>
      <div>J3s</div>
      <div>T3s</div>
      <div>93s</div>
      <div>83s</div>
      <div>73s</div>
      <div>63s</div>
      <div>53s</div>
      <div>43s</div>
      <div>33</div>
      <div>32o</div>

      <div>A2s</div>
      <div>K2s</div>
      <div>Q2s</div>
      <div>J2s</div>
      <div>T2s</div>
      <div>92s</div>
      <div>82s</div>
      <div>72s</div>
      <div>62s</div>
      <div>52s</div>
      <div>42s</div>
      <div>32s</div>
      <div>22</div>
    </div>
    <div class="carpetas">
      <div class="botones">
        <button id="principal_1">Redes Sociales</button>
        <div class="resto" hidden>
          <button>Facebook</button>
          <button>Twitter</button>
          <button>LinkedIn</button>
          <button>Gooogle</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="anuncios"></div>
  <div class="pie"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Votes are anonymous. Users can vote however they like, based on the perceived quality/usefulness of the question, and no one can tell how anyone else voted. Do not make assumptions about who voted what way, because those assumptions have no basis in reality. Under no circumstances should votes (which are anonymous) be discussed in comments. Do not leave comments complaining about votes, nor asking for other users to vote in a certain way, nor anything else about votes. Multiple comments of that type have been removed already, and this has led to the comments section being temporarily locked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I changed:

```
  .tablas_carpetas {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #DBE9EE;
}
.tablas {
  width: 50%;
  gap: 1%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #dfc0c0;
  height: 100%;
}
.tablas > div {
  background: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 35px;
  flex: 0 0 6%;
  margin: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.tablas_carpetas > .carpetas {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Here's a complete snippet:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.general {
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  margin-top: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #4f6d7a;
}
.enlaces {
  float: center;
  display: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #166088;
}
.tablas_carpetas {
  position:grid;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #DBE9EE;
}
.tablas {
  position:left;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction:column;
  order: 1;
  background-color: #dfc0c0;
  height: 300px;

}
.tablas > div {
  display:right;
  float:right;
  background: #ddd;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}
.tablas_carpetas > .carpetas {
  display:flex;

  position:left;
  order: 2;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
.anuncios{
  float: center;
  display: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
.pie{
  float: center;
  display: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}

.tablas_carpetas {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #DBE9EE;
}
.tablas {
  width: 50%;
  gap: 1%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #dfc0c0;
  height: 100%;
}
.tablas > div {
  background: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  flex: 0 0 7%;
  margin: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.tablas_carpetas > .carpetas {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#botones").mouseenter(function () {
      $("#resto").show();
    });
    $("#botones").mouseleave(function () {
      $("#resto").hide();
    });
  });
</script>
<div class="general">
  <div class="enlaces"></div>
  <div class="tablas_carpetas">
    <div class="tablas">
      <div>AA</div>
      <div>AKo</div>
      <div>AQo</div>
      <div>AJo</div>
      <div>ATo</div>
      <div>A9o</div>
      <div>A8o</div>
      <div>A7o</div>
      <div>A6o</div>
      <div>A5o</div>
      <div>A4o</div>
      <div>A3o</div>
      <div>A2o</div>

      <div>AKs</div>
      <div>KK</div>
      <div>KQo</div>
      <div>KJo</div>
      <div>KTo</div>
      <div>K9o</div>
      <div>K8o</div>
      <div>K7o</div>
      <div>K6o</div>
      <div>K5o</div>
      <div>K4o</div>
      <div>K3o</div>
      <div>K2o</div>

      <div>AQs</div>
      <div>KQs</div>
      <div>QQ</div>
      <div>QJo</div>
      <div>QTo</div>
      <div>Q9o</div>
      <div>Q8o</div>
      <div>Q7o</div>
      <div>Q6o</div>
      <div>Q5o</div>
      <div>Q4o</div>
      <div>Q3o</div>
      <div>Q2o</div>

      <div>AJs</div>
      <div>KJs</div>
      <div>QJs</div>
      <div>JJ</div>
      <div>JTo</div>
      <div>J9o</div>
      <div>J8o</div>
      <div>J7o</div>
      <div>J6o</div>
      <div>J5o</div>
      <div>J4o</div>
      <div>J3o</div>
      <div>J2o</div>

      <div>ATs</div>
      <div>KTs</div>
      <div>QTs</div>
      <div>JTs</div>
      <div>TT</div>
      <div>T9o</div>
      <div>T8o</div>
      <div>T7o</div>
      <div>T6o</div>
      <div>T5o</div>
      <div>T4o</div>
      <div>T3o</div>
      <div>T2o</div>

      <div>A9s</div>
      <div>K9s</div>
      <div>Q9s</div>
      <div>J9s</div>
      <div>T9s</div>
      <div>99</div>
      <div>98o</div>
      <div>97o</div>
      <div>96o</div>
      <div>95o</div>
      <div>94o</div>
      <div>93o</div>
      <div>92o</div>

      <div>A8s</div>
      <div>K8s</div>
      <div>Q8s</div>
      <div>J8s</div>
      <div>T8s</div>
      <div>98s</div>
      <div>88</div>
      <div>87o</div>
      <div>86o</div>
      <div>85o</div>
      <div>84o</div>
      <div>83o</div>
      <div>82o</div>

      <div>A7s</div>
      <div>K7s</div>
      <div>Q7s</div>
      <div>J7s</div>
      <div>T7s</div>
      <div>97s</div>
      <div>87s</div>
      <div>77</div>
      <div>76o</div>
      <div>75o</div>
      <div>74o</div>
      <div>73o</div>
      <div>72o</div>

      <div>A6s</div>
      <div>K6s</div>
      <div>Q6s</div>
      <div>J6s</div>
      <div>T6s</div>
      <div>96s</div>
      <div>86s</div>
      <div>76s</div>
      <div>66</div>
      <div>65o</div>
      <div>64o</div>
      <div>63o</div>
      <div>62o</div>

      <div>A5s</div>
      <div>K5s</div>
      <div>Q5s</div>
      <div>J5s</div>
      <div>T5s</div>
      <div>95s</div>
      <div>85s</div>
      <div>75s</div>
      <div>65s</div>
      <div>55</div>
      <div>54o</div>
      <div>53o</div>
      <div>52o</div>

      <div>A4s</div>
      <div>K4s</div>
      <div>Q4s</div>
      <div>J4s</div>
      <div>T4s</div>
      <div>94s</div>
      <div>84s</div>
      <div>74s</div>
      <div>64s</div>
      <div>54s</div>
      <div>44</div>
      <div>43o</div>
      <div>42o</div>

      <div>A3s</div>
      <div>K3s</div>
      <div>Q3s</div>
      <div>J3s</div>
      <div>T3s</div>
      <div>93s</div>
      <div>83s</div>
      <div>73s</div>
      <div>63s</div>
      <div>53s</div>
      <div>43s</div>
      <div>33</div>
      <div>32o</div>

      <div>A2s</div>
      <div>K2s</div>
      <div>Q2s</div>
      <div>J2s</div>
      <div>T2s</div>
      <div>92s</div>
      <div>82s</div>
      <div>72s</div>
      <div>62s</div>
      <div>52s</div>
      <div>42s</div>
      <div>32s</div>
      <div>22</div>
    </div>
    <div class="carpetas">
      <div class="botones">
        <button id="principal_1">Redes Sociales</button>
        <div class="resto" hidden>
          <button>Facebook</button>
          <button>Twitter</button>
          <button>LinkedIn</button>
          <button>Gooogle</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="anuncios"></div>
  <div class="pie"></div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps, the code for you to review in case you have doubts: https://jsfiddle.net/0kqzL6dn/37/

Comment: nearly ... thanks ... The chart has to stay fix, and the green container flexed .

Comment: To be fixed, you just need to add a `position: fixed;`, and also, I corrected the code to make the last item stay in the last line, and not in an additional line!

Comment: @manjirosano I just converted and added the snippet for your answer, I hope it helps.

Comment: Thx, but I added a jsfiddle link for that reason. Still, appreciated, and I hope that helps him ^^

Comment: @manjirosano Yes, you're right. Links might get rot. Great answer, thanks. `:)`

Comment: Oh yah, I forgot that detail. And thanks as well!